# Are angels ever depicted as having golden halos floating above their heads in the Bible?

Tags: the-bible

I remember having heard that many Christian ideas don't come from the Bible like the idea of Hell and Satan. I was wondering if golden halos were also an invention of the Christian Church and isn't mentioned in the Bible.

Comment: I believe Satan is mentioned by name in the book of Job. But you're right, that the usual depiction of his appearance and character is not Biblical. Among Christian denominations, at least the Catholics make no bones about the fact that the Bible is not the only source of their teachings. As for the haloes, my uninformed guess is that they were invented by Christian artists, or else reported by Christian mystics who had visions of angels and saints. Looking forward to learning from the answers, though I'm not sure this is the best stack exchange for the question.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(religious_iconography)

Comment: @repomonster in regards to your "pre-question" items: in the King James Version of the Bible Satan is mentioned 50 times, and the devil over a hundred more. "Hell" is mentioned over 50 times as well. Though of course how those two items are depicted in the actual Bible text may vary a lot from their current mainstream conceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only direct description of an angel in the Bible is in Revelation 10:1 (emphasis added):

> And I saw another mighty angel come down from heaven, clothed with a
>   cloud, **and a rainbow was upon his head**, and his face was as it were
>   the sun, and his feet as pillars of fire

Angels are also sometimes described in other Bible verses as having "glory" (e.g., Luke 2:9) and being surrounded by heavenly flame (e.g., Exodus 3:2, Judges 13:20).

Angels are mentioned around 300 times in the King James Version of the Bible (at least according to the concordance that I'm using), but very little is said about their physical appearance. They speak & sing, their faces and hands are mentioned, and they are sometimes implied to be passing as human.  They do occasionally use various implements - swords, trumpets, vials, etc. - and have various powers, including flight (Revelation 8:13).

So are angels depicted with halos in the Bible? No. But with such vague descriptions being given, you could argue that people were taking a valid level of artistic license when drawing pictures of these scenes.

*There are two other types of heavenly beings mentioned in the Bible that are often equated/associated with angels: seraphim and cherubim. Seraphim are mentioned just once, in Isiah 6:2, and are described as having "six wings." Cherubim are described a bit differently than angels and most of the references appear to be about statues of them rather than actual cherubs. Cherubs can fly (2 Samuel 22:11) and have wings (1 Kings 6:24) and hands (Ezekiel 10:7).*